# Is it common to shorten 感じがする to 感じ?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

Whilst it isn't always the case, I do occasionally see sentences that I think would be written out in full as 感じがする as opposed to 感じ. Take the following examples.

> お風呂って大好きなんです。心が休まる感じで
>   心が休まる感じがするのでお風呂が大好きなんです

or

> 恋した時ってどんな感じがするんですか
>   恋した時ってどんな感じなんですか

So my question is:

Is it relatively common in normal speech to abbreviate 感じがする＞感じ?(If this is just me me misunderstanding and this isn't actually done, then please explain the differences in meaning between two suitable sentences)

Comment: If two phrases share a word, does that automatically make the shorter one an "abbreviation" for the other?   Maybe sometimes, but not in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

感じ(だ) is more colloquial than 感じがする, but I would say they're also slightly different. 感じだ doesn't necessarily have something to do with feelings, e.g.

> そんな感じ(だ) (It's) something like that

Likewise 恋した時ってどんな感じなんですか *could* be asking about other circumstances than feelings, although feelings would be an obvious topic when talking about love: "What's it like to fall in love" whereas 感じがする is asking more specifically about feelings.

心が休まる感じで *could* lean more towards the translation "it's like I become rested" than "I feel rested".

It's hard to describe the difference with your examples, since they're already talking about stuff that has to do with feelings. But you could imagine a conversation like:

> 朝はどんな感じ？ What are your mornings like?
>   起きて朝ごはんを食べて、急いで家を出る I wake up, eat breakfast and hurry out the door

where 感じがする would seem a bit unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

I think in spoken / casual Japanese, 「感じがする」is often abbreviated as 「感じ」, but it is fine to use 「感じがする」.

- スカイダイビングってどんな感じがするの? --> スカイダイビングってどんな感じ？
- この部屋はなんだか怪しい感じがする --> この部屋はなんだか怪しい感じだ

Answer (score 0):

For the most time, you can use 「感じがする」 and 「感じ」 interchangeably (if you're referring to feelings). If I were to give a difference between those two, I would say that with 「感じがする」, you are more conscious about how it feels. 「恋した時ってどんな感じがするんですか」 could be translated to "What does it feel like to fall in love?" whereas with 「感じなんですか」 I might translate it to "What's it like to fall in love?"